# GoogleAnalytics hit to wrong view

Tags: post, web-applications, google-analytics

I have a problem. The sent data from the SDK mobile to analytics go to the wrong view. I'd like them to go to the type-view "APP" but they go to the website view instead. I've tried to set up the "APP" data source but it doesn't work. Screenviews are correctly send to the "APP" view but events are send to the wrong "website" view.

I use a basic POST call to send my events. My payload is similar to this:

```
"v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXY&cid=555&ec=video&ea=play&el=holiday&ev=300&ds=app"
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Data does not go into views, data goes into properties. Views merely display the same data by different criteria. So you cannot change the data you see in views via the tracking code, you need to check and adapt the filters on your views.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the data is not stored in the views but in the properties.

Unless you have a very good reason not to, I suggest having separate properties for apps and websites. That means different tracking-IDs.

If you absolutely want to store both in a single property and don't want to see them in the same view, you'd have to look into Google Analytics Filters. Using filters, you can easily create separate views for app and web traffic.

This is how a filter that excludes all App traffic would look like:

[image]

More about filters on [this link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en).

Comment: Not work for me. I have made the same filter but not work.

Comment: Okay, but would having App and Website in separate views be an option for you?

Comment: Now there are in separate view. For you the best thing is to put them in separate properties?

Comment: Having them in separate properties id definitely the best way to go, unless you have a really good reason to keep them in a single property.